# what to use, GDB or LLDB debuggers for xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, debugging, xcode4

Okay, I have just been through a massive amount of bull craparooonie with xcodes new LLDB debugger.

pretty much spent the better most of the day working on an error with my simulator that occurred after updating the debugger to LLDB.. so after figuring it all out I have rolled back to the GDB debugger by changing it in **prefrences > edit scheme > debugger** back to GDB.
This has solved my issues for now, however I have a question.

Apple are moving to a new set of LLVM suite of tools, I would like to know what I should do, is rolling back to GDB and waiting for a more stable version of LLDB to roll out a good idea? or can you think of something better?

pretty much my question is how best to handle the new upgrading of the xcode tools :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is always to use what works the best for you.  I also keep GDB active despite xcode complaints.  LLDB gives bogus results often.

Comment: okay, sounds good.. yes I have also read about these bogus results from LLDB.. why would apple do such stupid stuff.

Comment: Like any new tool it still has things that need ironing out.  Once it matures more I am sure it will be fine.